# What mantras does the Ramakrishna mission provide to the people who take mantra Diksha?

Tags: mantras

Ramakrishna mission provides the mantra Diksha to the devotees. As I am also interested in mantra Diksha , I wanted to know what types of mantras will be provided by the Ramakrishna mission if I want to be initiated? Will the mantra be as per my choice of deity or the deity which my guru chooses for me ?